# Using reduce to remove like elements

Tags: javascript

https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/sorted-union

Write a function that takes two or more arrays and returns a new array of unique values in the order of the original provided arrays.

I've solved this problem with this code:

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  var arg = arguments[0];
  var newArr = [];
  var i = 0;
  var matchFound = false;  

  //start newArr with each element of arg
  while(i < arg.length){
    newArr.push(arg[i++]);
  }

  //iterate over the argument sets
  for(i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
    //iterate over the argument set values
    for(var j = 0; j < arguments[i].length; j++){
      //compare each value with arg values 
      for(var k = 0; k < arg.length; k++){
        if(arg[k] === arguments[i][j]){
          matchFound = true;
        }
      }
      if(!matchFound){
        //if no comparison was found add element to newArr
        newArr.push(arguments[i][j]);
      }
      //reset matchFound 
      matchFound = false;
     }
  }

  return newArr;
}

// Function Call
uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]); //returns [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]
```

My question is how would I solve this problem using .reduce and are there other ways that I could clean this up a bit to make it easier to read?

Comment: So is your code functional, is it supposed to return `[1, 3, 2, 5, 4]` ? I'd think `[3, 5, 4]` would be the right answer ?

Comment: Appears to be returning [1, 3, 2, 5, 4] for me.  Is .reduce a must?

Comment: Yes, this code runs as expected and returns the correct answer. There is a 'helpful link' on each puzzle and this one had reduce as the helpful link. I wanted to see if someone could show me how to use reduce and/or some other way to solve the same problem. I just feel like the 3 for loops are a bit messy and that there is a cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: I would say take a look at the [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) methods

Comment: I agree this code isn't lean.  We can do better, but didn't know if reduce is a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine `reduce` with `filter`.

```js
var uniteUnique = [[1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]]
.reduce( (a, b) => {
  return a.concat(b)
})
.filter( (x, idx, arr) => arr.indexOf(x) == idx )

console.log(uniteUnique)
```

But there is actually no need to use reduce at all.

You could just

```
var uniteUnique = [1, 3, 2].concat([5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1])
    .filter( (x, idx, arr) => arr.indexOf(x) == idx )

console.log(uniteUnique)
```

Comment: `concat()` takes multiple arguments, you would just do `[1,3,2].concat(secondArray,thirdArray,...)` no need to pipe the arrays through `reduce`. Or in the case of OP using `arguments` use the spread operator: `[].concat(...arguments)`

Comment: You are absolutely right. There is no need to use reduce at all here. Let me fix that.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly and was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just giving one more option incase the data is big and we don't want to create a big array and filter it down.

```js
function uniteUnique(arr) {
    var result = [].concat.apply(arguments[0]);

    for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {    
        for(var j = 0; j < arguments[i].length; j++) {
            if (result.indexOf(arguments[i][j]) === -1) {
                result.push(arguments[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
    
// Function Call
console.log(uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1])); //returns [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]
```

Comment: `[].concat.apply(arguments[0])` is less code as `arguments[0].slice()`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(
 (function() {
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arguments)
  .reduce(function(accumulator, iterand) {
   return accumulator.indexOf(iterand) === -1
   ? accumulator.concat(iterand)
   : accumulator
  }, []);
 })([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate over the arrays and read the value and update the output if that doesn't exist in the output already.

```js
let inputArrays = [[1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]]
let outputArray = [];
inputArrays.forEach((array) => {
  array.forEach((value) => {
    if(!outputArray.includes(value)){
      outputArray.push(value);
    }
  })
});

console.log(outputArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to use reduce without creating a big array first is like Will has done: assume the first array has no duplicates and iterate over the other arrays, adding members that aren't in the collated array.

I've use *Array.from* to create an array of arguments, but you could also do:

```
return [].reduce.call(arguments, ...)
```

```js
function uniteUnique() {
  return Array.from(arguments).reduce(function(a, b) {
    b.forEach(function(v) {
      if (a.indexOf(v) == -1) a.push(v);
    });
    return a;
  },[]); 
}

console.log(uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]));
```

Here's an arrow function version, but I don't think it saves much:

```js
function uniteUnique() {
  return Array.from(arguments).reduce((a, b) => {
    b.forEach(v => {if (a.indexOf(v) == -1) a.push(v)});
    return a;
  },[]); 
}

console.log(uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

With `[].slice.call(arguments)` create an array of arrays *coming* from the arguments.

```
function f(arr1, arr2, arr3) {
    var arrays = [].slice.call(arguments); // [arr1, arr2, arr3]
}
```

Then go through the array containing arrays with `reduce()` an **unify** them with `concat()`. Return an array with [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) from a [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

A `Set()` allows only unique values.

**In total**

```js
var a = [1, 3, 2],
  b = [5, 2, 1, 4],
  c = [2, 1],
  d = [9, 3];

function uniteUnique(arrays) {
  var arrays = [].slice.call(arguments), // An array with arrays
    array = arrays.reduce((a, b) => { // Go throug array with arrays
      return a.concat(b); // to concat them
    })
  return Array.from(new Set(array)); // Create array from Set; Set only has unique values!
}

var r = uniteUnique(a, b, c, d);
console.log(r);
```

**Compact**

```js
var a = [1, 3, 2],
  b = [5, 2, 1, 4],
  c = [2, 1],
  d = [9, 3];

function uniteUnique(arrays) {
  return Array.from(new Set([].slice.call(arguments).reduce((a, b) => {
    return a.concat(b);
  })));
}

var r = uniteUnique(a, b, c, d);
console.log(r);
```